# Export to Unreal Engine without combining all the elements in one object

Tags: export

In **Blender** I have a cupboard with the doors. When I export it to the **Unreal Engine** (*.fbx file), I want to be able open/close this doors in my game. But in **Unreal** I have only 1 object and in **Blender** - 5.

What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This could be an engine issue. I recall that when importing there is an option to combine meshes.

Comment: If you come to a solution, please answer your own question so other people can see how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Blender I put a moving part of the object at the center of origin and export the object separately. It works for me. Zero coordinate in Blender will be pivot point in Unreal

[image]